# jquery disable button until TWO select fields chosen

Tags: jquery

I have a form where I have multiple fields, but it's essential that two of the dropdowns at least are chosen, and until they are, i disable and relabel the submit button

I am using the following for one of the fields, is there a way to double up, id of other field is #list_name

So, #category and #list_name must be chosen with a value before submit is enabled

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#category').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                $('#btn_show').addClass('button green');
                $("#btn_show").attr('value', 'Add To My List');

            } else { 
                $('#btn_show').removeClass('button green'); 
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true); 
                $("#btn_show").attr('value', 'Choose a category and list for your item');
            }
        });

});
```

I've tried using normal jquery multiple:

```
$('#category', '#list_name').change(
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be

```
$('#category, #list_name').change()
```

This one looks for the category element inside of the context of list_name

```
$('#category', '#list_name').change()
```

the entire code would look something like this

```
$('#category, #list_name').change(
        function(){
            if ($('#category').val() && $('#list_name').val()  ) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                $('#btn_show').addClass('button green');
                $("#btn_show").attr('value', 'Add To My List');

            } else { 
                $('#btn_show').removeClass('button green'); 
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true); 
                $("#btn_show").attr('value', 'Choose a category and list for your item');
            }
        });
```

Comment: If this doesn't work - maybe because your code is generated by another piece of code - use the `live` selector: `$('#category, #list_name').live('change', function() {`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue since it seems to work for one of the select elements for him. Also, as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. It's suggested to use .on() to attach event handlers that need to be delegated

Comment: Well noted! I'm living in the past you see.