# Enable button until select fields will chosen

Tags: jquery, html, select, button

I try to make button enabled/disabled status until user will choose 4 select boxes.
I based on this solution: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr59d/) from here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095278/jquery-disable-button-until-two-select-fields-chosen) but in my case I can't make it working. Here is my fiddle:  <strike>[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr59d/)</strike> http://jsfiddle.net/marekandrzejak/nYCz6/, what I do wrong?

HTML:

```
<form action="classes/script.php" method="POST" name="pricelist" style="float:left;">
<div class="price_list option">
    <label for="choose_currency">Wybierz walutę</label>
    <select id="choose_currency" name="choose_currency">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Wybierz...</option>
        <option value="1">PLN</option>
        <option value="<? echo $obj->getGBPRate() ?>">GBP</option>
        <option value="<? echo $obj->getEurRate() ?>">EUR</option>
        <option value="<? echo $obj->getUSDRate() ?>">USD</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="price_list option">
    <label for="vat">Podatek VAT</label>
    <select id="vat" name="vat">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Wybierz...</option>
        <option value="23">23%</option>
        <option value="0">0% WDT</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="price_list option">
    <label for="discount">Rabat</label>
    <select id="discount" name="discount">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Wybierz...</option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value="5">5%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="15">15%</option>
        <option value="20">20%</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="price_list option">
    <label for="language">Język</label>
    <select id="language" name="language">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Wybierz...</option>
        <option value="7">Polski</option>
        <option value="1">Angielski</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button class="button minibutton" id="pricelistBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Pobierz"><span class="mini_icon mini_icon_zapisz"></span>Pobierz</button>
```

SCRIPT (in head):

```
$('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $(document).ready(

    function updateFormEnabled(){
    if (verifyAdSettings()) {
        $('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', '');
    } else {
        $('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }


function verifyAdSettings() {
    if ($('#choose_currency').val() != '' && $('#vat').val() != '' && $('#discount').val() != '' && $('#language').val() != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
$('#choose_currency').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#vat').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#discount').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#language').change(updateFormEnabled);
}
);
```

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be working fine?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine..

Comment: to me too....seems exactly what u want : button disable until u select both drop down

Comment: Your fiddle and the code you posted here are different! But even your posted code seems to be working fine!

Comment: Wrong link to my fiddle - sorry. Here is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/marekandrzejak/nYCz6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/89PYB/

```
$('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
function updateFormEnabled(){
    if (verifyAdSettings()) {
        $('#pricelistBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}

function verifyAdSettings() {
    if ($("#choose_currency option:selected").val() != '' && $("#vat option:selected").val() != '' && $('#discount option:selected').val() != '' && $('#language option:selected').val() != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#choose_currency').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#vat').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#discount').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#language').change(updateFormEnabled);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go...

```
   $('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   $(document).ready(

   function updateFormEnabled(){
   if (verifyAdSettings()) {
        $('#pricelis`enter code here`tBtn').attr('disabled', false);     // set false over here not ''
    } else {
        $('#pricelistBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }


function verifyAdSettings() {
    if ($('#choose_currency').val() != '' && $('#vat').val() != '' && $('#discount').val() != '' && $('#language').val() != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
$('#choose_currency').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#vat').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#discount').change(updateFormEnabled);
$('#language').change(updateFormEnabled);
}
);
```